# Column to a Row in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, datatable

I use laravel and DataTable

laravel back data

[image]

i need display data about like this

[image]

I managed not to duplicate the lines, but I do not know how to dynamically change the header and transfer the data from the column to it

my try

```
                    table = $('#table').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        iDisplayLength: 50,
                        bStateSave: true,
                        order: [[1, "desc"]],
                        dom:
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-2'B><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
                        renderer: 'bootstrap',

                        rowsGroup: [// Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified order to which rows grouping is applied
                            // (column-selector could be any of specified in https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)

                            'id:name'
                        ],
                  
                        ajax: {
                            url: "{{url('api/get-data')}}",
                            type: 'POST',

                            "data": function (d) {
...
                            }
                        },
                        autoFill: true,
                        columns: [
                            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                            {data: 'count_1', name: 'count_1'},
                            {data: 'count_2', name: 'count_2'}
                        ],
```

});

result

[image]

Comment: Something like this: [DataTables doc for child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) ?

Comment: you can get header also from ajax, column names for header

Comment: you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644755/2996989)