# Python DataFrame df.to_json(orient='split') - Doesnt maintain Order of Column Labels

Tags: python, pandas

Am using - Python 3.5.4 , pandas==0.23.0
[image: JSON as seen in Django Template]

The Pandas DataFrame created from Six Lists shown below - each for a Column.

```
    ls_col_1 = ["Col_1_Row_1","Col_1_Row_2","Col_1_Row_3"]
        ls_col_2 = ["Col_2_Row_1","Col_2_Row_2","Col_2_Row_3"]
        ls_col_3 = ["Col_3_Row_1","Col_3_Row_2","Col_3_Row_3"]
        ls_col_4 = ["Col_4_Row_1","Col_4_Row_2","Col_4_Row_3"]
        ls_col_5 = ["Col_5_Row_1","Col_5_Row_2","Col_5_Row_3"]
        ls_col_6 = ["Col_6_Row_1","Col_6_Row_2","Col_6_Row_3"]

df_xls = pd.DataFrame({'ZaaCol_A':ls_col_1,'MCol_B':ls_col_2,'BCol_C':ls_col_3,'XCol_3':ls_col_4,'Col_E':ls_col_5,'Col_F':ls_col_6})   

data = json.loads(df_xls.to_json(orient='split'))

dict_json['data_json'] = data

return JsonResponse(dict_json, safe= False)
```

The json i get to see in a Django template is as below :-

```
{"data_json": {"columns": ["BCol_C", "Col_E", "Col_F", "MCol_B", "XCol_3", "ZaaCol_A"], "index": [0, 1, 2], "data": [["Col_3_Row_1", "Col_5_Row_1", "Col_6_Row_1", "Col_2_Row_1", "Col_4_Row_1", "Col_1_Row_1"], ["Col_3_Row_2", "Col_5_Row_2", "Col_6_Row_2", "Col_2_Row_2", "Col_4_Row_2", "Col_1_Row_2"], ["Col_3_Row_3", "Col_5_Row_3", "Col_6_Row_3", "Col_2_Row_3", "Col_4_Row_3", "Col_1_Row_3"]]}}
```

The Question is - Why does the - "columns": within the --     {"data_json":, not maintain the given Order of Column Labels . Rather the Column Labels get Alphabetically sorted ?

Further i call this JsonResponse - dict_json , into DataTables.js and there the Columns maintain their Linkage with the Columnar Data - but the labels are Alphabetically sorted ?

This behaviour changes as i assign Column Labels to the Python DataFrame as seen below - but defeats the purpose of my code . I do not want to feed in the Column Labels after having created the DataFrame.

Below gives desired results :-

```
df_xls.columns = ['ZaaCol_A','MCol_B','BCol_C','XCol_3','Col_E','Col_F']
```

A related question would be here - [Keep column and row order when storing pandas dataframe in json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572359/keep-column-and-row-order-when-storing-pandas-dataframe-in-json/43572422)

but doesnt help me .

Also if it helps - the SO Question from where i took my down stream DataTables.js code . But that totally depends on what JSON im feeding the DataTable thus just for ref... [How to display the column headers dynamically in jquery data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644079/how-to-display-the-column-headers-dynamically-in-jquery-data-table)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What versions of Python and pandas are you using?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta - Python 3.5.4 , pandas==0.23.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
df_xls = pd.DataFrame({'ZaaCol_A':ls_col_1,'MCol_B':ls_col_2,'BCol_C':ls_col_3,'XCol_3':ls_col_4,'Col_E':ls_col_5,'Col_F':ls_col_6})
```

is creating a python dict that is passed to the DataFrame constructor. In python versions < 3.7, dicts are unordered. You have two options, use an OrderedDict (from collections) or pass lists of data values and column names in the DataFrame constructor.

Ie:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([('ZaaCol_A', ls_col_1),('MCol_B',ls_col_2),
    ('BCol_C',ls_col_3),('XCol_3',ls_col_4),('Col_E'k,ls_col_5),('Col_F',ls_col_6)]))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ls_col_1, ls_col_2, ls_col_3, ls_col_4, ls_col_5, ls_col6],
                  columns=['Col_A', 'Col_B', 'Col_C', 'Col_D', 'Col_E', 'Col_F'])
```